# ASP.NET - Nested DataList, stored value from Parent in the Hidden Field in child DataList

Tags: asp.net

I have a Parent datalist (DataList1) and a child datalist (childList). Is there a way to store the field Value (Company) from DataList1 (parent) in the hidden field (hiddenCompanyFromParent) inside the child DataList (childList), so I can process it later?

Please help....

```
<asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataSourceID="dsCompanyListPartialMatch"  runat="server" Width="80%" DataKeyField="Company1Word"
    UseAccessibleHeader="true"
    CssClass="books"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="item"
    AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="alternating" 
    GridLines="Both"
    CellPadding="0"
    CellSpacing="0" BorderColor="Black"
    ItemStyle-BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="0"
     HorizontalAlign="Center"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
    >                
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr class="div_hover">
            <th style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; "></th>
            <th style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">Num</th>
            <th style="width: 70%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">Company Name</th>
            <th style="width: 10%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">Add?</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemStyle BorderColor="black" Font-Size="Medium" />

    <ItemTemplate>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr class="div_hover">
            <td style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">        
            <asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="+" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'
                OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"  
                Font-Underline="false"       
                Height="25"      
                Font-Bold="true"                  
                ></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0; text-align:right; padding-right:10px;"><%#Eval("Row")%></td>
            <td style="width: 70%"><asp:Literal ID="ltlCompany" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Company")%>' /> </td>

            <asp:Label ID="lblRow" Visible="False" runat="Server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Row") %>' />
        </tr>    
        </table>      
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="padding-left:200px;">
                <asp:DataList ID="childList" runat="server" Width="100%">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <div  class="div_hover">
                        <table class="table1" width="80%">
                       <tr>
                          <td style="width: 60%; border-right:0px solid black; border-spacing:0;">&#8226; <%#Eval("CompanyName")%></td>
                           <td style="width: 20%;text-align:right; "><a href="/Apps/ERP/Other/CompanyInfo.asp?CompanyID=<%#Eval("CompanyID")%>" ><%#Eval("CompanyID")%></a></td> 

                           <td style="width: 20%;text-align:right;"><asp:CheckBox id="chkChildCompany" runat="server" value="123Test"
                                AutoPostBack="true"
                               OnCheckedChanged="chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged" CustomAttribute='<%#Eval("CompanyID") %>' /></td>
                           <asp:Label ID="hidden" Visible="True" runat="Server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompanyID") %>' /> 
                           <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCompanyFromParent" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Company FROM PARENT DATALIST1") %>' />                    
                       </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:DataList>
           </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>

     <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>                
</asp:DataList>
```

I try this code below, but it is not working either.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCompanyParent" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, "DataItem.Company")%>' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hidden field is deep inside DataList-->Panel-->Child DataList. In this case you have to dig deeper:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCompanyFromParent" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.Parent.Parent.Parent, "DataItem.Company")%> ' />
```

**EDIT:** You are rebinding the child DataList in link button's click event, so the parent datalist's data is not available after postback. One thing you can do, add a hidden field out side the child Datalist. Here I am adding inside the panel:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="padding-left:200px;">
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCompany" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company")%> ' />
```

Now in the code you can find the hidden field's value and use it. Even you can assign this value to the hidden field inside child DataList:

```
protected void childList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HiddenField hdnCompany = (HiddenField)e.Item.NamingContainer.Parent.FindControl("hdnCompany");
        HiddenField hdnChildCompany = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hiddenCompanyFromParent");

        if (hdnCompany != null && hdnChildCompany != null)
        {
            hdnChildCompany.Value = hdnCompany.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And use the value from any of the hidden field.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. But there is a problem it keep resetting that hiddenField.  I have the "OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" on DataList1, which will get a list of companies and place under childList, then the childList.Bind() at the end Event keep resetting the childList, so those values in the hiddenField are gone. any suggestion?

Comment: Then I would recommend setting the hidden field value in childList_ItemDataBound method.

Comment: I following your instruction got it to work. Thank you so much for taking time to put the sample code and explaining. Appreciated!